# Create custom Function or Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a `Hierarchy` table with `Master_id` and `Sub_id`.

```
sub_id Master_id
2      1
3      2
4      1
5      3
6      7
```

I want to create an iterative function or stored procedure (I am not sure I never used any of  them before) to create one more column which gives me the `primary_master_Column` (PMC)

```
sub_id Master_id PMC
2      1         1
3      2         1
4      1         1
5      3         1
6      7         7
```

Comment: It's uncleart to me what you want.

Comment: Sorry I renamed the columns in my table. In my table 3 is a subsidiary of 2. but 2 in turn is a subsidiary of 1. So I want a separate column which would list the id which is on the top of the hierarchy. Hope am clear now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
  Master_id, sub_id, 
  max(PMC) keep(dense_rank first order by lev desc) as PMC
from
(
select 
  sub_id as PMC, level lev, 
  connect_by_root(Master_id) as Master_id,
  connect_by_root(sub_id) as sub_id
from your_table
connect by prior sub_id = Master_id
)
group by Master_id, sub_id
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5bda9/1)

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/53bb7/9)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test (sub_id, Master_id) AS
          SELECT 2,      1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3,      2 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 4,      1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 5,      3 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 6,      7 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT t.sub_id,
       t.master_id,
       CONNECT_BY_ROOT( t.master_id ) AS PMC
FROM   test t
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       test x
       ON ( t.master_id = x.sub_id )
START WITH x.sub_id IS NULL
CONNECT BY PRIOR t.sub_id = t.master_id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/53bb7/9/0)**:

```
| SUB_ID | MASTER_ID | PMC |
|--------|-----------|-----|
|      2 |         1 |   1 |
|      3 |         2 |   1 |
|      5 |         3 |   1 |
|      4 |         1 |   1 |
|      6 |         7 |   7 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT t.sub_id,
       t.master_id,
       CONNECT_BY_ROOT( t.master_id ) AS PMC
FROM   test t
START WITH NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 'x' FROM test x WHERE t.master_id = x.sub_id )
CONNECT BY PRIOR t.sub_id = t.master_id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/53bb7/9/1)**:

```
| SUB_ID | MASTER_ID | PMC |
|--------|-----------|-----|
|      2 |         1 |   1 |
|      3 |         2 |   1 |
|      5 |         3 |   1 |
|      4 |         1 |   1 |
|      6 |         7 |   7 |
```

Comment: Thanks for your time on this.. I will try to get this to work using the CONNECT BY

Comment: Could you please explain why you were using PRIOR DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE IS NOT NULL condition??..thanks,AVG

Comment: It is [used to stop loops](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2191579?tstart=0) in the data - when I wrote the first draft of the query it was necessary to include it but I subsequently added in the `START WITH` statement and now the `AND PRIOR DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE IS NOT NULL` is redundant and can be removed. I'll edit it out of the answer so as not to confuse.